# Migrating from old Macbook Pro to a new Macbook Pro

Tags: eclipse, terminal, migration, keychain, macos-mojave

While migrating from a old 2015 Macbook Pro to a new 2019 Macbook Pro, how do I copy IDEs like Eclipse with all the configuration intact?

I have several applications like Eclipse, Microsoft Remote Desktop, Keychains, Terminals with profiles.

Is there a way to get everything running in new Macbook Pro exactly as it was (in the older one) without sweating much?

Comment: Look at [macOS migration assistant](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204350)

Answer (score 0):

I asked this question. At the moment, it looks like the easiest way is to clone the old Mac drive and restore it in new Mac. I have not yet tried it.

Answer (score 0):

From MAC to MAC, The best solution is to use [Migration Assistant for Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204350) .

Have a good day